Alter a value in excel based on the current date
I have a table that follows when something needs to be checked. For example, I have a column that has the dates of when something should be checked and another column that shows if the thing is valid or not depending on the date.
For example, I have a tool that needs to be checked at 21.10.24, so that tool is still valid because today is 13.10.24. Each tool has a row with a column on which date that tool should be checked. So I want an Excel to automatically say if the tool is valid or not. Not valid means that the check date passed, and it should be checked. I hope I explained it well.
I didn't try anything, now I enter manually if a tool is valid or not. I know it's possible to make Excel do it for me.

I think you mean something like this ?

if yes, the formula is the following :
=IF(B2<=TODAY();"Yes";"No")

